# Почему не работает if в последнем условии?

Tags: java

```
package supreme;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    static   byte[] tempCrypt;
    static  short [] crypting;
    static  char [] password;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        menu();
    }
    //[S@7225790e
    public static  void menu() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        System.out.print("1.Crypt\n2.Uncrypt\n3.Exit\nPlease make your choice: ");
        switch(choice = in.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your string which will be crypted: ");
                String line = in.next();
                tempCrypt = line.getBytes();
                crypting = new short[tempCrypt.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < tempCrypt.length; i++ ) {
                    crypting[i] = tempCrypt[i];
                }
                System.out.println("Please enter your password(it can be any number): ");
                int tempPassw = in.nextInt();
                String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(tempPassw);
                System.out.print("Password is: ");
                System.out.println(temp);
                password = temp.toCharArray();
                for (int i =  0; i < crypting.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(crypting[i]);
                }

//                ____CRYPTING
                int counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < crypting.length; i++) {
//                    System.out.println("Length is:" + crypting.length);
//                    System.out.println("Counter is:" + counter);
                    if(counter == crypting.length || counter > crypting.length) counter = 0;

                    if((password[counter] == '1') && (password[counter+1] == '0')) {
                        crypting[i] = (short)(crypting[i] << 1);
//                        System.out.println(crypting[i]);
//                        System.out.println("<<");
                    }
                    if(password[counter] == '0' && password[counter+1] == '1') {
                        crypting[i] = (short)(crypting[i] >> 1);
//                        System.out.println(crypting[i]);
//                        System.out.println(">>");
                    }
                    if(password[counter] == '1' && password[counter+1] == '1') {
                        crypting[i] = (short)(~crypting[i]);
//                        System.out.println(crypting[i]);
//                        System.out.println("~");
                    }
                    counter+=2;
                }
                System.out.println("After crypt:");
//                for( int i = 0; i <crypting.length; i ++ ) {
//                    System.out.println("Element " + i +" is: " +  crypting[i]);
//                }
                String temparory = new String();
                for (int i = 0; i < crypting.length; i++ ) {
                    temparory  +=  Short.toString(crypting[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(temparory.getBytes());
                String news = new String(temparory);
                System.out.println(news);
                System.out.println(temparory);

                _________________________________________________________
                !!!Вот этот кусок почему то игнорируется программой!!!!!!
                System.out.println("Exit program?(y/n)");
                String answer = in.next();
                if(answer=="yes") {
                    break;
                } else {
                    menu();
                }


            }
            case 2:
            {
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Please, choose one of the possible variants:");
                menu();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте answer.equals("yes")

Comment: Может, потому, что в вопросе (y/n), а не (yes/no)? Что вы вводите?

Comment: Спасибо,помогло.

Comment: Дело в том, что сравнение вида "==" для примитивов (int, byte, boolean и прочие не-классовые) сравнивает их по содержимому, то есть то, чего мы интуитивно хотим. String - это класс, объект, но не примитив. "==" для объектов сравнивает, ссылаются ли две ссылки на один объект. Когда вы хотите сравнить два объекта на содержимое, используется метод .equals(), наследуемый от Object. Теперь на вашем примере подробней: вы создали ссылку answer типа String, записали в нее ввод с консоли. В условии вы также создали строку "yes" без ссылки. == сравнило ссылки и дало ответ: они разные. Притом всегда.

Comment: Рекомендую прочитать Oracle Certified Associate 7 ([OCA 7](https://github.com/iChrist/java/blob/master/Sierra%20K.%2C%20Bates%20B.%20-%20OCA%20OCP%20Java%20SE%207%20Programmer%20I%20%26%20II%20Study%20Guide%20-%202015.pdf)), там в главе, кажется, 5 (глава о работе со строками) этот вопрос очень доступно и качественно раскрывается.